# Function overloading in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, overloading

I have defined some types:

```
type box = Box of int
type table = Table of int
type compare_result = Lt | Eq | Gt
```

It seems that in OCaml, we can't define 2 functions with same name but different types of arguments:

```
let compare (a: box) (b: box): compare_result = (...)
let compare (a: table) (b: table): compare_result = (...)

let res_box = compare (Box 1) (Box 2) in (* which is supposed to call the first funciton *) 
let res_table = compare (Table 1) (Table 2) in (* which is supposed to call the second function *)
```

So could anyone tell me what is the alternative in OCaml to do this? Do we have to name these 2 functions differently?

Comment: Please note that your second declaration of `compare` will hide the previous one (there's no function overloading in Ocaml).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the easiest solution is simply to call the functions differently. Allowing programs that do this vastly complicates the type system (not to the point that it isn't possible for experts to design a solution: to the point that you would find it unusable when they do).

Existing solutions for writing a single function `compare` are the object system in OCaml, and type classes in Haskell (a different extension to the same base type system). But it's much simpler to stay in the simple fragment and to name your functions `compare` differently.

Comment: Another alternative to creating compare_box and compare_table is to wrap each type and compare function in their own module.  You would then call Box.compare and Table.compare.

Comment: Creating separate modules is also convenient if you plan on creating a `Set` or `Map` from the type.

Comment: hmmm still is nice to have the same name for the method/function, so OCaml has no overloading at all?